# How to dynamically add rows that contains input tag with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new in this field, and didn't know where to ask.

I want to make a input form using table. But, i don't know how many rows that needed, so i want to make this table as flexible as it can so users can add more rows as much as their need.

I tried to look at tutorial and answers about this type of question, but i still cannot make my code work.

So, i hope you can help me find the right code for this. Thank you so much.

This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src = "jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type = "text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tambah").click(function () {
     var markup = "<tr><td><input type = "number" ID = "no" placeholder = "1"/></td><td><input type = "text" ID = "tahapan" placeholder = "Tahapan 1"/></td><td><input type = "text" ID = "suboutput" placeholder = "Sub-Output 1"/></td></tr>";
     $('#table2 tbody').append(markup);
    });
   });
  </script>
  <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "prosesbisnis.css" media = "screen">
  <title>
   Proses Bisnis Kegiatan Pokok
  </title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class = "main">
   <h1>Proses Bisnis Kegiatan Pokok</h1>
   <br>
   <br>
    <table class = "table">
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td class = "col1">Nama Unit Eselon I</td>
       <td class = "col2"> : </td>
       <td class = "col3">
        x
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class = "col1">Nama Satuan Kerja</td>
       <td class = "col2"> : </td>
       <td class = "col3">
        x
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class = "col1">Nama Unit Organisasi</td>
       <td class = "col2"> : </td>
       <td class = "col3">
        x
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class = "col1"><br></td>
       <td class = "col2"><br></td>
       <td class = "col3"><br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class = "col1">Nama Kegiatan</td>
       <td class = "col2"> : </td>
       <td class = "col3">
        x
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class = "col1">Definisi Kegiatan</td>
       <td class = "col2"> : </td>
       <td class = "col3">
        x
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class = "col1"><br></td>
       <td class = "col2"><br></td>
       <td class = "col3"><br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class = "col1"><br></td>
       <td class = "col2"><br></td>
       <td class = "col3"><br></td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
    <table id = "table2">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>No</th>
       <th>Tahapan</th>
       <th>Sub-Output</th>
       <th></th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <br>
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td><br></td>
       <td><br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <input type = "number" ID = "no" placeholder = "1"/>
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type = "text" ID = "tahapan" placeholder = "Tahapan 1"/>
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type = "text" ID = "suboutput" placeholder = "Sub-Output 1"/>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
    <p>
     <input type = "button" id = "tambah" value = "Tambah">
    </p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
   <center>
    <a href = "">
    <div class = "submit">submit</div>
   </center>
    <br>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: change **just outer quotes** in `var markup = ""` from double quotes to single quotes

Comment: I'll try it. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double quotes is the problem in you script code, either change those into single quotes or replace `"` with `\"`

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#tambah").click(function () {
                var markup = "<tr><td><input type = \"number\" ID = \"no\" placeholder = \"1\"/></td><td><input type = \"text\" ID = \"tahapan\" placeholder = \"Tahapan 1\"/></td><td><input type = \"text\" ID = \"suboutput\" placeholder = \"Sub-Output 1\"/></td></tr>";
                $('#table2 tbody').append(markup);
            });
        });
```